# How do I change the thickness and color of \hline on a table simultaneously?

Tags: tables

It is easy to change the color or thickness of \hline in a table, but I want to change color and thickness which is hard for me...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
  a \\
  \arrayrulecolor{green}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The thickness of `\hline` is controlled by `\arrayrulewidth`. It can be changed globally inside `\noalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth=2mm}
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
  a \\
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth=1mm}
  \arrayrulecolor{green}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Is there anyway to change the color of \hhline? Also, is there any way to change the thickness locally?

Comment: @H.R. a) The method of the answer should also work for `\hhline`, see also "9 More fun with `\hhline`" in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) of package `colortbl`.

Comment: b) Also `\arrayrulecolor` uses a global definition internally. At the start of a new table row, TeX expands tokens. An assignment ends the expansion mode and starts the new cell already. As a workaround, the previous thickness can be saved in a register and restored afterwards.

Comment: What is the default thickness of hline?

Comment: @Viesturs It depends on the document class, the standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) and other (`memoir`, ...) define `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}`. Then, the default thickness is 0.4 pt.

Comment: I have a 2500 page book pdf that has lots of tables in it.  Would `\renewcommand{\hline}{\arrayrulecolor{myColor}\hline}` work ?  Any better suggestions ?