# \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} vs \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

Tags: pgfplots

Using TexShop 3.92 on mac OS X El Capitan V 10.11.6

1.13 works but not 1.15?
Error: Choice '1.15' unknown in choice key 'p

What to do?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (20000,0.0005)
        (40000,0.0010)
        (60000,0.0020)    };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `compat` number refers to version numbers for the `pgfplots` package. By setting the `compat` you tell `pgfplots` to use settings/features from that specific version.

If `1.15` doesn't work, that means you don't have version 1.15 of `pgfplots` installed. The `compat` setting can not look into the future.

Just use `1.13`, or possibly try `1.14`.

If you want to update `pgfplots`, you might be able to use the TeX Live Utility to do that, see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55438#55438), assuming you're using MacTeX.

Comment: Thank you so much, but from `compat` it is so hard to guess that this is actually version.

Comment: @user1700890 Not sure if I understand, but if you want to figure out which version you actually have installed, you can use `\pgfplotsversion`, e.g. `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{pgfplots} \begin{document} \pgfplotsversion \end{document}`.

Comment: I actually could not get `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` to work with `compat =1.10`. Took me forever to figure out that this is due to version. `compat =1.11` solved it. I guess `compat` is for compatability.

Comment: @user1700890 Well yes, `compat` is short for compatibility. However, the `fillbetween` library can work perfectly fine with `compat=1.10`, or even no `compat` setting, try for example the first example in the section of the manual describing the library. So if you want to understand why your code failed with 1.10, make a complete example and ask a question about it. The one change I know about from 1.10 to 1.11 is that a coordinate such as in `\draw (1,2) ..` will be interpreted as being in `axis` coordinates with 1.11, but not with 1.10 where you'd need `\draw (axis cs:1,2)` for the same res.

Comment: Good point, posted: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532832/interaction-between-compat-1-10-compat-1-11-and-fillbetween