# Fraction ticks on a pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to use pgfplots to produce a plot with fractional ticks on the y-axis. Unfortunately pgfplots doesn't deal very nicely with things like `yticks = {1/36, 1/18, 1/12, 1/9, 5/36, 1/6}`, and gives various errors about how to represent them.

In the end, I got fed up and scaled my plot so that it passes through integer points instead. However, I'd still like to have the fractional ticks in their lowest form, because currently I have
[image]
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
   \pgfplotsset{
      standard/.style={
         axis x line=middle,
         axis y line=middle,
         enlarge x limits=0.15,
         enlarge y limits=0.15,
         every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0.1)},anchor=north west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(0.1,1.1)},anchor=north},
         every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=white}}
      }
   }
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      standard,
      domain = 2:12,
      samples = 11,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$\Pr(X=x)$},
      ymin=0,
      yticklabel={$\frac{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}{36}$},
      ytick = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
      ymax=6]
      \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] {(6-abs(x-7))};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to go about the whole thing? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Write `yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}/{36}$}` instead of `yticklabel={$\frac{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}{36}$}`

Comment: @Cragfelt Still makes no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, so you would like to write the simplified fractions like `1/36, 1/18, 1/12, 1/9, 5/36, 1/6`, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two possible options to achieve this:

1. Just need to write `yticklabels={$1/36$, $1/18$, $1/12$, $1/9$, $5/36$, $1/6$}` for simplified fractions (or `yticklabels={$1/36$, $2/36$, $3/36$, $4/36$, $5/36$, $6/36$}`, if you will), or with common fraction displaying by using       `yticklabels={$\frac{1}{36}$, $\frac{1}{18}$, $\frac{1}{12}$, $\frac{1}{9}$, $\frac{5}{36}$, $\frac{1}{6}$}`. Or
2. write `yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}/{36}$}` instead of
   `yticklabel={$\frac{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}{36}$}`.

Note, the difference between them is that with the first one, you write `yticklabels=...` and mention labels one by one at will (simplified or non simplified), and with the second one, you write `yticklabel=...` with the automatic generating code (but will display *non simplified* fractions).

### Simplified fractions

[image]

### Common fraction displaying

[image]

### Non simplified fractions

[image]

Also, to place the `ylabel` above the vertical line and centered, you can put

```
every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
```

---

And just to let you know, it is important to include the line

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
```

in preamble when using PGFPlots. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403018/pgfplotssetcompat-1-13-vs-pgfplotssetcompat-1-15/403020#403020) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. As you indicated in the comments earlier, yes, I wanted them simplified.

Comment: @LukeCollins Thank you for accepting my answer and upvoting it. I included both alternatives for you to have them and for others to choose as well.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way, making use of `gcd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\Fraction}[2]{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmpNumerator}{#1/gcd(#1,#2)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmpDenominator}{#2/gcd(#1,#2)}
\ensuremath{\frac{\tmpNumerator}{\tmpDenominator}}
}
\begin{document}
   \pgfplotsset{
      standard/.style={
         axis x line=middle,
         axis y line=middle,
         enlarge x limits=0.15,
         enlarge y limits=0.15,
         every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0.1)},anchor=north west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(0.1,1.1)},anchor=north},
         every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=white}}
      }
   }
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      standard,
      domain = 2:12,
      samples = 11,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$\Pr(X=x)$},
      ymin=0,
      yticklabel={$\Fraction{\tick}{36}$},
      ytick = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
      ymax=6]
      \addplot+[ycomb,black,thick] {(6-abs(x-7))};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]