# Use fractions for coordinate ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractions, ticks

So I have some issues with the rounding of fractions, and I know that calculating fractions is notoriously difficult for a computer, so I am not too surprised this is not as easy as I want it to be.

I want my y-coordinate ticks to be fractions, and I want them to be the ones I gave as arguments (i.e. 1/36, 2/36, ...):

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines =center,
ytick={(1/36),(2/36),...,(6/36)},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/frac},
ymin=0, ymax = 0.2,
xmin=0, xmax = 1.4]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {1/36 * x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the result are...some less compelling fractions:

[image]

PS: I don't know what exactly the fp package does, but Overleaf recommended using it (it didn't resolve my issue though).

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410354/47927 ?

Comment: That already helps quite a bit. I do want the non-simplified fraction version, and I can live with spelling them all out, I guess I'll never have that many of them. If there's a not too complicated way to automate that with something like the a,...,b-system, I'm still interested, but this is definitely good enough for now. I wonder why I didn't find the thread while searching.

Thanks for the link!