How can I get `f(2/3) = 20/9` and `f(4/3) = 16/9` of the function f(x) = 3 *x^3 - 9*x^2 + 8*x when I use pgf/tikz
Based on this answer, I am trying to calc f(2/3) and f(4/3) of the function f(x) = 3 *x^3 - 9*x^2 + 8*x, my code
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  declare function={%
      a=3;b=-9;c=8;d=0;
      f(\x)=a*\x*\x*\x+b*\x*\x+c*\x+d;
          }
  ]
  \pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/number format/frac,
       /pgf/number format/frac whole=false,
  }
   \pgfmathparse{f(2/3)}%
   $ f\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)=
   \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$
   
   \pgfmathparse{f(4/3)}%
   $ f\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)=
   \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}  

I got 
How can I get f(2/3) = 20/9 and f(4/3) = 16/9?

PGF isn't a symbolic computation engine the way that Maple, Mathematica, or SymPy are. It's parsing 2/3 and 4/3 as float division, then passing the result into your function f(\x). The resulting calculation is a float, which is then converted into a fraction based on the available precision when you pass in /pgf/number format/frac. Consequently, that's why you're getting results that are almost, but not quite, the values you want.

You can probably trick this with 'fpeval'.  In the most general case you will probably have to make friends with 'SageTeX' - this basically allows you to do things that you could do with Sagemath, Mathematica, Maple, etc.

Can you compile with LuaTeX then this sort of thing is so much easier and accurate.

I get the first result f(2/3) correctly with \usepgflibrary{luamath}, the second f(4/3) unfortunately never works correctly (maybe someone can do it); so I didn't pursue this path any further. I'm afraid you'll need SageTeX for something like that, as mentioned. As far as I know, LaTeX calculates point measurements for drawing accuracy, and is therefore unfortunately difficult to misuse as CAS.

You can make the computations with xintexpr.  But I don't know how this can be injected into tikz/pgf. \usepackage{xintexpr}, \xintdeffunc f(x):=reduce(3x^3-9x^2+8x+0);, \xinteval{f(2/3)}, \xinteval{f(4/3)}, etc...

f(x)=((3*x-9)*x+8)*x is standard form for applied math.  (Fewest ops and least roundoff error.)

You might use pythontex to do the computations.  You would have the results and be able to use them in tikz for example.

Below, a key declare xintexpr function is defined. This must be a function of one variable named \x. It will define the function for pgfmath and also for \xintdeffunc.
Also a key number format/xintexpr is defined. If true then \pgfmathprintnumber will use \xinteval. Otherwise, \pgfmathprintnumber will behave as usual.
Therefore, the commands \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathprintnumber are redefined.
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l__pgfmathxintexpr_xinteval_bool

\tl_new:N \l__pgfmathxintexpr_function_tl
\tl_new:N \l__pgfmathxintexpr_parse_tl

\cs_new_eq:NN \__pgfmathxintexpr_pgfmath_parse_old:n \pgfmathparse

\cs_new_eq:NN \__pgfmathxintexpr_pgfmath_print_number_old:wn \pgfmathprintnumber

\pgfkeys
  {
    / pgf / declare~xintexpr~function /. code =
      {
        \tikzset { declare~function = { #1 ; } }
        \tl_set:Nn \l__pgfmathxintexpr_function_tl { #1 ) ; }
        \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__pgfmathxintexpr_function_tl { \x } { x }
        \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l__pgfmathxintexpr_function_tl { = } { : = reduce ( }
        \exp_after:wN \xintdeffunc \l__pgfmathxintexpr_function_tl
      } ,
    / pgf / number~format / xintexpr /. code = \bool_set:Nn \l__pgfmathxintexpr_xinteval_bool { \cs:w c_#1_bool\cs_end: } ,
    / pgf / number~format / xintexpr /. default = true ,
    / pgf / number~format / xintexpr = false
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand \pgfmathparse { m }
  {
    \__pgfmathxintexpr_pgfmath_parse_old:n {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l__pgfmathxintexpr_parse_tl {#1}
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand \pgfmathprintnumber { O {} m }
  {
    {
      \pgfkeys { / pgf / number~format , #1 }
      \bool_if:NTF \l__pgfmathxintexpr_xinteval_bool
        {
          \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#2} { \pgfmathresult }
            { \xinteval { \l__pgfmathxintexpr_parse_tl } }
            { \xinteval {#2} }
        }
        { \__pgfmathxintexpr_pgfmath_print_number_old:wn [#1] {#2} }
    }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare xintexpr function={f(\x)=3*\x*\x*\x-9*\x*\x+8*\x+0}}%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/xintexpr}%
\pgfmathparse{f(2/3)}%
$f\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)$\\
\verb|\pgfmathresult| gives \pgfmathresult\\
\verb|\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult| gives \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult\\
and\\
\pgfmathparse{f(4/3)}%
$f\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)$\\
\verb|\pgfmathresult| gives \pgfmathresult\\
\verb|\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult| gives \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult
\end{document}



How can I put your  \pgfkeys{/pgf/declare xintexpr function into \tikz` like my question?

I see that, we can not define function f(x) more than one time in the same document'

@ThuyNguyen This can be achieved with \begin{tikzpicture}[declare xintexpr function={f(\x)=3*\x*\x*\x-9*\x*\x+8*\x+0}] \node {\pgfmathprintnumber[xintexpr]{f(1/2)}}; \end{tikzpicture}.

@ThuyNguyen It is possible to define a function f(\x) more than one time in the same document. Inside the same scope, this can be done with \pgfmathredeclarefunction. Otherwise, the example from the previous comment can be placed one after another with both f(\x) and possibly different functions.

very interesting!

I think \xintdeffunc f(x):=RHS; can have its right hand side use \x if at this point you have \def\x{x} (I checked right now it works, you can even write f(\x):=stuff with \x; as long  as it is under scope of \def\x{x}).  I don't know if it is feasible but it would be a bit lighter than tl_replace_.... But we are talking milliseconds probably...

@user691586 Thank you! That is indeed possible but if \def\x{x} is used then \x will be overwritten if it was already defined, which could occur in a tikzpicture.

@matexmatics can you answer this question?

@matexmatics ah yes obviously you are right.  And I don't know how to exfiltrate an xintexpr function to outside scope of a group so I don't know offhand how you could add a group to limit \def\x{x}.  Update: I found about \xintglobaldefstrue (2.10.8 page 49 of their docs). Hmm, no, no good: xintexpr may be used elsewhere in document prior and after tikzpicture and an f could be defined before and used after...

@matexmatics you may save and restore the \x. How brilliant this is? ;-).  Anyhow this is minor point.  Again thanks for this answer I will bookmark it.

@ThuyNguyen perhaps your linked question predates this one? Wouldn't it be easier if it was on this  site, as follow-up?

@user691586 This question was  posted first.

@ThuyNguyen See for example this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410354.
