# Interaction between `compat = 1.10`, `compat = 1.11` and `fillbetween`

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This post is continuation of the discussion starting in the comment to the following post [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403018/pgfplotssetcompat-1-13-vs-pgfplotssetcompat-1-15/403020?noredirect=1#comment1347314_403020)

The following code works perfectly fine, but if I change to `compat = 1.10` shading disappears. I am curious why? Also commenting `%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` removes shading.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1, xmax=3,
        ymin=-1, ymax=3,
        axis lines=middle,
      ]  
      \addplot [gray, name path = A] coordinates {(0, 1) (1, 1)};

      \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

      \addplot[gray, pattern=north west lines] fill between[of=A and xaxis, soft clip={domain=1/2:1}];

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my final comment, with `compat=1.11` a coordinate used with `\draw` (and also the other "normal" TikZ drawing commands, including `\path`), will be assumed to be in axis coordinates. With `1.10` it will not be.

Hence, in `\path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);` the path doesn't actually run along the x-axis if you have `compat=1.10` or no `compat` setting at all.

If you change to

```
\path[name path=xaxis] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
```

the switch to the axis coordinate system is explicit, and it will work as expected regardless of `compat` setting.

Below is a complete example demonstrating the difference. A blue line is drawn with `axis cs`, a red line without. You can see the red line in the bottom left of this screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1, xmax=3,
        ymin=-1, ymax=3,
        axis lines=middle,
        clip=false % added just for this example
      ]  
      \addplot [gray, name path = A] coordinates {(0, 1) (1, 1)};

      % here we use axis cs:, so it works
      \draw[blue, ultra thick, name path=xaxis] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

      % here we don't, so it doesn't work (in the way you expected)
      \draw[red, ultra thick] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);


      \addplot[gray, pattern=north west lines] fill between[of=A and xaxis, soft clip={domain=1/2:1}];

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```