# Vertical line causes 'dimension too large' error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, dimensions

For the following plot (with time axis) I would like to add a bold, red vertical line at index 2010-01-01.

[image]

But I always run into a `Dimension too large` error. How can I solve this issue?

Here is the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    max space between ticks=25pt,
    scale only axis=true,
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
    tick style={black, thick},
    ylabel={},
    ymax=700000,
    %ymin=0,
    grid=major,
    enlarge x limits = false,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    xticklabel = {\year},
    x tick label style={align=center},
    date coordinates in=x,
    table/col sep=comma,
    date ZERO={1991-01-01},
    xmin={1991-01-01},
    xmax={2021-01-01},
    xtick={1992-01-01, 1994-01-01, 1996-01-01, 1998-01-01, 2000-01-01, 2002-01-01, 2004-01-01, 2006-01-01, 2008-01-01, 2010-01-01, 2012-01-01, 2014-01-01, 2016-01-01, 2018-01-01, 2020-01-01},
    xticklabels={1992, 1994, 1996, 1998, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2018, 2020}
]
 
\addplot[black] table[x={month}, y={commits}, col sep=comma] {commits.csv};
\addplot[red, dashed] table[x={month}, y={0}, col sep=comma] {commits_growth.csv};

%\draw [red, dashed] ({2010-01-01}, 0) -- ({2010-01-01}, 700000); % causes 'Dimension too large' error

\end{axis}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: We don't have your data files, so we can't test your example. Can you make an example that doesn't rely on those files, or supply a sample of the files, sufficient to reproduce the problem? As always, it's appreciated if you can make a minimal but complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, so it can be tested without modifications.

Comment: Do you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`  (or some higher version number) anywhere, by the way?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem: With some dummy data, the document `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}\begin{document}`... your code ... `\end{document}` compiles fine.

Comment: As hinted at above, I suspect this is essentially the same thing as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532832/  If you don't have a `compat` setting of 1.11 or higher, coordinates for `\draw` etc. inside an `axis` environment are *not* assumed to be in the coordinate system of the axis. So 2010-01-01 is probably read as a normal numeric coordinate for the `tikzpicture`, not a date coordinate in the axis. Either add the mentioned `compat` setting, or use `axis cs` to explicitly use the axis coordinate system, e.g. `(axis cs:{2010-01-01}, 0)` instead of `({2010-01-01}, 0)`.

Comment: Oh stupid me. Indeed, the compat solved everything. Sorry for bothering you all. @TorbjørnT. since you were the first one who pointed this our, I would gladly accept your answer.