# Tables and Picture inside a main table

Tags: tables

Is it possible to achieve something like this in Latex? My knowledge on tables is kind of limited. I can create the two columns, but how can I add the two tables inside the first column, and the picture in the second column?
[image]

**EDIT:**

As I'm writing in another language, some words are a bit longer, which is affecting my table. This what I have:
[image]

This is my code:
Either way I need more consistency in the format.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Designación de capacitancias}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!20}\textbf{Capacidades parasitarias y de baja señal} & $C_{ies},\;C_{oes},\;C_{res} = f(V_{CE})$\\\hline
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l@{\hskip6mm}>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l}
\textbf{Capacitancias} & \textbf{Designación}\\\myhline
$C_{GE}$&Capacitancia puerta-emisor\\\myhline
$C_{CE}$&Capacitancia colector-emisor\\\myhline
$C_{GC}$&Capacitancia puerta-colector\\(capacitancia Miller)\\\myhline
\end{tabular}\\[.2cm]
\begin{tabular}{>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l@{\hskip6mm}>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l}
Capacitancias\\de baja señal & Designación\\\myhline
&\\\myhline
&\\
\end{tabular}}
&
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figures/gate2}}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What is your question after the edit? How to break lines in a tabular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple tabular:

[image: tabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Parasitic and Low-Signal Capacitances & $C, C, C = f(V)$\\\hline
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Capacitances & Designations\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Capacitances & Designations\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
&
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

*Edit:* Added your colors (with the nice code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410346)):

[image: table 2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}

\newcommand\myhline{\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth=1pt}\arrayrulecolor{white}\hline}

\arrayrulecolor{gray!80}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!20}Parasitic and Low-Signal Capacitances & $C, C, C = f(V)$\\\hline
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l@{\hskip6mm}>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l}
Capacitances & Designations\\\myhline
&\\\myhline
&\\
\end{tabular}\\[.2cm]
\begin{tabular}{>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l@{\hskip6mm}>{\cellcolor{gray!20}}l}
Capacitances & Designations\\\myhline
&\\\myhline
&\\
\end{tabular}}
&
\parbox{.45\textwidth}{\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've update my question showing my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tcolorbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster height=10cm, sharp corners,colframe=gray,colback=white,fonttitle=\bfseries,
raster column skip=-1pt,]
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={Tables}]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Capacitances & Designations\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Capacitances & Designations\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={Figure}]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, something like that is fine. I'm now reading the tcolorbox package.

Comment: You could use a tcbraster which would be easier than to manually do its work.

Comment: @TeXnician with `tcbraster` also I will be having the same number of `tcolorbox`s. Isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean with same number? You will have two tcolorboxes and the tcbraster, but you do not need to take care of the width settings, of the equal height group and would have a more flexible approach.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you for the suggestion. I updated my answer with `tcbraster`

Comment: Much better, +1 :)