# \Xcline (makecell) doesn't lign up with \vrule

Tags: tables, longtable, rules, makecell

I'm not sure how to fix this problem where the `\Xcline` from `makecell` doesn't lign up with the `\vrule` I set in my `longtable`(need that since the actual table might span several pages).

Here is a MWE of said problem:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{c!{\vrule width 1.5pt}c!{\vrule width 1.5pt}c}
        \Xcline{2-3}{1.5pt}
        A & B & C \\
        \Xcline{1-3}{1.5pt}
        A & B & C \\
        \Xcline{2-3}{1.5pt}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The problem I'm having is, that the small square between the last \Xcline and the \vrule is remaining white (I'm guessing this happens because the \vrule leaves space for a horizontal line, but the \Xcline is just filling the space below the cell - but I don't really know how to fix this).

[image: Here is the compiled MWE]

I tried adding extra table rows that don't have `\vrule`s , but that doesn't work either. If `makecell` is the problem I wouldn't mind switching to another package if there are other suggestions, I don't really need any other `makecell` functionalities.

Comment: for an alternative how to design nice table see: http://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/. After seeing this presentation you my be convinced, that vertical rules are not nice nor important for readability of table ...

Comment: I was kind of expecting this reply somewhere, read it all over the place when people ask stuff about vertical rules. Thank you for your suggestion, but there is a reason I'm using vertical rules and I cannot omit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background of your table is not know. However, as I said in my  comment, I would think again if the vertical lines are really needed, i.e. do you not like to have professional looking table (as suggested in given link) ...

Suppose, that you need such rules in whole table than the following suggestion can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulewidth=1.5pt
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c }
    \hhline{~|--}
  1 & 2 & 3     \\
    \hhline{-|--}
  4 & 5 & 6     \\ 
    \hhline{~|--}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, that's what I was looking for, I previously forgot the ```|``` in the ```\hhline```. Since I am not the one resposible for how the table is supposed to look it's off the table to leave out vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

The example below will point you in the right direction since it combines color with thickness using the `\arrayrulecolor` and `\arrayrulewidth` command which can be applied globally--the permutations are clearly seen in the example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\arrayrulewidth=2mm
\begin{tabular}{
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 l
 |
 c
 !{\color{blue}\vrule width 2pt}
 c
 ||
}
 one & two & three\\
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3\\%
\noalign{
\color{yellow}
\hrule height 5pt
}%
4&5&6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You may also like to see--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337790/197451

Does this suit your requirements?

If you feel the answer is as per your requirements please upvote the answer by clicking on the red triangle at the left and the tick mark below it

Comment: This does not solve my problem sadly. I replaced the last ```\hline``` with a ```\hhline{~--}``` and it still shows the same behavior where the vertical and the horizontal rule don't connect. Thank you for your effort though!

Answer (score 0):

With the version 6.11 (2022-07-16) of `nicematrix`, it's possible to define commands similar to the command `\cline` with characteristics of Tikz lines (eg: thickness with the Tikz key `line width`).

In the following example, I have also used the Tikz key `shorten <` in order to have a perfect junction with bold vertical rules.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}    

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I ,
       tikz = { line width = 1.5 pt } , 
       total-width = 1.5pt 
     } ,
    custom-line = 
     {
       command = boldline , 
       ccommand = cboldline ,
       tikz = { line width = 1.5pt , shorten < = -1.5pt } , 
       total-width = 1.5pt 
     }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{cIcIcIc}[cell-space-limits=5pt]
    \cboldline{2-3}
    A & B & C & D\\
    \cboldline{1-3}
    A & B & C & D\\
    \cboldline{2-3}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes used by `nicematrix`).

[image: Output of the above code]